# search ID in string mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a column A contains of ID

```
ex: 1113 992 981 778 718
```

and my query

```
select product 
from something 
where userInvite like '% 1113 %'
```

It will be fine, but if it on only contains one string

```
 ex: 1113
```

and query returns there is no results, but if I remove space, it will be fine

E.g.:

```
select product 
from something 
where userInvite like '%1113%'
```

How can I fix it, to search ID in case the column A is not contains a space and contains space.

Comment: Can you explain what is it that you need to fix?

Comment: Is ID always at the beginning of the field? Always followed by a space? Will there be a space before it sometimes?

Comment: @Minh Anh welcome to SO.  If you received the answer to your question, don't forget to accept it, or vote it up; it's good manners here.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do it, would be to use comma as separator, then you could just simply use mysql built in function: [find_in_set](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set).

In this case, we can do a little trick:

```
select product 
from something 
where find_in_set('123', replace(product, ' ', ',')) > 0
```

See demo here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bfcbc/2/0

Comment: I appreciate that you also show the case of searching for a string that matches another id e.g. '%123%' matches '12345' partially but is not desired as result

Answer (score -1):

`select product from something where userInvite like '%1113%'` should work

Heres a [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/351a1/1)

Comment: but what happen if we search like this     select * from tab where str like '%13%'

Comment: @MinhAnh : Then you have serious design issue.